# How to prevent a node from speeding up too much?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have nodes that fall from the top of my scene and are set to speed up like so:

```
   var droptime: NSTimeInterval = 20.5

 class GamePlayScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
       droptime = 20.5

    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock(array),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(1.6)])))





  func array()  {

  let colorCount = 5

    let index=Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colorCount)))

    let dots = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Color\(index+1)")
    dots.position = CGPointMake(150, 600)
    dots.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(45, 45))
    dots.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    dots.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    for i in 0..<5 {
        dots.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(0x1 << index)
        dots.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = UInt32(0x1 << index)

    }
   addChild(dots)

             droptime -= 1.09
          dots.size = CGSizeMake(45, 45)
    dots.runAction(
        SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -1600,
            duration: NSTimeInterval(droptime)))


}
```

}

And as time goes on, obviously they keep speeding up and eventually fall too fast for gameplay. I was wondering if there was a way that once they reach a certain speed, that they'll just stay at that speed so that they don't end up falling obnoxiously fast and the game becomes unplayable.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using gravity for falling objects?

Comment: No, I just set it to false by default. Would changing it to true have an effect?

Comment: Gravity by nature makes things accelerate as they fall. Works well for falling objects. I'll post a simple fix in your case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a `max` on the drop time.

```
let minInterval = 5.0 //min interval of 5 sec
//minInterval is your smallest time interval desired - that's how you can limit speed
droptime = max(droptime - 1.09, minInterval)
```

Comment: I never thought of this. Would the `minInterval` be set up just like my `droptime` variable?

Comment: yea, you could declare `minInterval` anywhere as long as its accessible in the function. i wouldn't redeclare it every time if it isn't going to change. You could declare it where you declare dropTime

Comment: Okay, I just declared it in my `array()` function and it works beautifully. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an `if` case that checks the droptime and decrements it only if it is greater than the some minimum time.

```
if droptime > minTime:
    droptime -= 1.09
```